# Placing x beside fixed error alert

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am customizing the bootstrap alert message so its fixed at the top of the page. The only problem is i cant seem to get the `x` button to be to the right of the message. It looks like this (the `x` is the little red at the top):

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
```

and here is the css:

```
.alert-info {
   position: fixed;
   display: block;
   top: 10px;
 }

.close {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
```

How can i get the `x` to be vertically centered with the alert and to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DLY6Y/19/

For this type of alert message I would use the light red one. For the fixed positioning I would add the extra custom class alert-fixed.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable alert-fixed">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><strong>Warning!</strong> Invalid email or password.</div>
```